# Python: how to merge several lists with same variable types into one list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix, row

How to combine three lists of lists into one so that the first strings of second-level lists would appear in the first row of the new list of lists and corresponding second strings - in the next rows (one row for each list)?

Let's say there are three lists of lists that look as follows:

```
[['item_1', 'price_100'], ['item_2', 'price_200']] #from shop_a
[['item_1', 'price_120'], ['item_2', 'price_180']] #from shop_b
[['item_2', 'price_80'], ['item_3', 'price_220']] #from shop_c
```

I'd like to merge them into a single list of lists like this:

```
[['item_name', 'shop_a', 'shop_b', 'shop_c'], #should become the header of the DataFrame
['item_1', 'price_100', 'price_120', ''], #should become the 1st row of the DF
['item_2', 'price_200', 'price_180', 'price_80'], #should become the 2nd row of the DF
['item_3', '', '', 'price_220']] #should become the 3rd row of the DF
```

The idea is to get all prices for the same item in each row, so that the DataFrame constructed from the list would represent a convenient matrix to compare prices from different shops.

How to do this? I would appreciate any suggestion...

PS: Please consider that the rows are not equal in length (the third list is different from the first two).

Comment: What are you tried so far?

Comment: @GPhilo Thank you, but if I follow the answer for that question I get this:
`
               shop_a               shop_b               shop_c
0  [item_1, price_100]  [item_1, price_120]   [item_2, price_80]
1  [item_2, price_200]  [item_2, price_180]  [item_3, price_220]
`
So that solution requires rows to be of the same length and items to be in the same sequence, what is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store them in a `dictionary` using the item name as the key then sort them alphabetically and create a `df`, for example this:

```py
import pandas as pd


a = [['item_1', 'price_100'], ['item_2', 'price_200']] #from shop_a
b = [['item_1', 'price_120'], ['item_2', 'price_180']] #from shop_b
c = [['item_2', 'price_80'], ['item_3', 'price_220']] #from shop_c

data = {}
for item in a + b + c:
    item_name = item[0]
    item_price = item[1]
    item_data = data.get(item_name, ['', '', ''])
    item_data.append(item_price)
    item_data.pop(0)
    data[item_name] = item_data

sorted_rows = sorted([
    [item_data[0]]+item_data[1] for item_data in data.items()
], key=lambda item: item[0])

df = pd.DataFrame(sorted_rows, columns=['item_name', 'shop_a', 'shop_b', 'shop_c'])
print(df)

>>>
  item_name     shop_a     shop_b     shop_c
0    item_1             price_100  price_120
1    item_2  price_200  price_180   price_80
2    item_3                        price_220
```